# Undefined method `user' in Posts>Show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Getting this error in posts>show when I try to load up a form.

The form is for users to send messages to each other. Grateful for any feedback!

Thanks.

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show

Showing /Users/fkhalid2008/loand/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `user' for #<Post:0x12e2ae930>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_remote_tag (:update => 'message', :url => {:controller => 'main', :action => 'send_message', :user_id => @post.user.id}) do %>
2: <br>
3: <br />
4: <br />
```

---

**POSTS>SHOW VIEW**

```
<%= form_remote_tag (:update => 'message', :url => {:controller => 'main', :action => 'send_message', :user_id => @post.user.id}) do %>
<br>
<br />
<br />
<div class="field">
Hello! My name is <%= f.text_field :subject %> and I'm contacting you in response to your ad. I'm interested in learning more so get in touch! Here's my contact details: <%= f.text_field :body %>.
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn span6 large">Submit</button>
<% end %>
```

**POSTS CONTROLLER**

```
def new
@post = Post.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @post }
end
end

def edit
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
        if verify_recaptcha && @post.save
            format.html { redirect_to :action=> "index"}
            format.json { render :json => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json { render :json => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**MAIN CONTROLLER**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

def send_message
message = Message.new
message.subject = params[:subject]
message.body = params[:message]
message.sender = User.find session[:user]
message.recipient = User.find params[:user_id]
if message.save
  ContactMailer.deliver_message_email message.recipient.email, message.id, request.host
  return redirect_to "/posts"
else
  render :text => "Hmm. Something seems to be wrong...let me look into it"
end
```

**CONTACT MAILER**

class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base

```
def message_email (recipient, id, host)
recipients   [ recipient ]
subject      "Weddoo: You have received a new message"
from         "admin@weddoo.com"
bcc          ["admin@weddoo.com"]
content_type "text/html"
body         :message_id => id, :host => host
sent_on Time.now
end

end
end
```

**ROUTES.RB**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users do
 resources :messages
   end

resources :profiles
resources :pages
resources :posts

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

**POST MODEL**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :job, :location, :salary

validates :title, :job, :location, :salary, :presence => true 
validates :salary, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 1} 

default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is saying there is no method `user` on the `Post` model. It points you directly to the first line.

```
<%= form_remote_tag (:update => 'message', :url => {:controller => 'main', :action => 'send_message', :user_id => @post.user.id}) do %>
```

so I'd say

`@post.user.id` is your problem statement, that model doesn't have a method `user` but it's hard to know for sure without seeing the Post model.

Comment: i added the post model above. so can i fix this with belongs_to :user, or is there more to it?

Comment: @hikmatyar yes that should fix the problem, don't forget to add the `has_many :posts` to the user model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed to add relationship.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```